# Svelte {#if variable} block does not react to variable updates within the block

Tags: html-table, svelte

I would like to populate a table with visible rows in Svelte.

My current attempt relies on a {#if variable} test, where the rendered row updates the variable. Unfortunately, the test does not appear to react to changes to the variable. Perhaps this is as designed but the [documentation](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-if) does not appear to address this. Essentially:

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
      {#each rows as row}
          {#if renderIt==true}
            <tr use:updateRenderIt>
                <td>cell</td>
            </tr>
          {/if}
      {/each}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I think my understanding of the timing is lacking :(. Perhaps the {#if} block cannot react to each renderIt change. There are quite a few examples of {#if} blocks, but none appear to rely on a variable which is changed within the block.

There is a [running example in the Svelte playground](https://svelte.dev/repl/dd8651fec63b4d58ab3e4df6ba04c416?version=3.55.1). The console divider can be moved vertically to change the viewport dimensions.

If someone knows of a way to achieve this it would be appreciated! I can do it in traditional Javascript, but my Svelte expertise is limited :).

Comment: Can you also show the code where `renderIt` is created, and how `updateRenderIt` is implemented (in the same file as the Svelte component?)?

Comment: The {#each} block does appear to react to changes in the variable controlling its looping [based on this Svelte playground](https://svelte.dev/repl/dd8651fec63b4d58ab3e4df6ba04c416?version=3.55.1). I don't know whether this is canonical Svelte, but it seems to work for my purposes. If someone knows of a better way, please respond.

Comment: Apologies, Peppe.. the problematic code is, as advertised, in the [Svelte playground](https://svelte.dev/repl/dd8651fec63b4d58ab3e4df6ba04c416?version=3.55.1)

Comment: Please always include all relevant code *in the question*. Also, your REPL is broken and different from the code in the question.

Comment: ah.. my mistake.. it seems that the old REPL was overwritten by the new REPL during my exploration. The [new REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/92049eca6e3e41ddbfc4d47b4ffcea2e?version=3.55.1) appears to work, but there is a puzzling, though pleasing, "-1 is not a function" at the base of the console. I do not know where that comes from.

Comment: There's one variable `renderIt`. If this is set to false, all rows won't be rendered. You might want to have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API or a library like https://github.com/skayo/svelte-tiny-virtual-list to only render visible elements

Comment: The `-1 is not a function` is due to `args.rows.filter(i)` which expects a function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?retiredLocale=de (as already mentioned, better include all relevant code in the question)

Comment: ah.. i see.. that would explain why the {#each} block is breaking (at the desired point).. a rather common request :). Will fix and see if it addresses the issue. I'm not hopeful. I have already done this in Javascript, Corrl.. porting it to Svelte-ish would be nice.

Comment: As already mentioned - better include the relevant code in the question. And be aware, that the Repl might be modified after the link has been shared. And if you mention someone, add a @ before the name so that he gets notified. And there's always a way with Svelte... :)

Comment: [this appears to work](https://svelte.dev/repl/4501039211944155bbd0078c07736c92?version=3.55.1). It renders up to the second invisible row. I don't fully understand the lifecycle of the various pieces, but changing the {#each} rows variable does appear to work.

Answer (score 0):

What I'm assuming you want is to have a state on each row when it is visible.

To do so you will need to store some data with your row, so instead of your row being a list of numbers and a single boolean to say if all rows are visible or not, it will be a list of objets that have a property visible:

```
let rows = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  rows.push({
    index: i,
    visible: false,
  });
};
```

Next, to capture when visibility changes on those rows, use Intersection Observer API:

```
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(
  (entries, observer) => {
    console.log(entries);
  }
);
```

And use a svelte action to add that observer to elements:

```
<script>
  ...

  let intersect = (element) => {
    observer.observe(element);
  };
</script>

<table>
  <tbody>
    {#each rows as row (row.index)}
      <tr
        use:intersect>
        <td>{row.visible}</td>
      </tr>
    {/each}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

To pass the intersecting state back to the element throw a custom event on it:

```
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(
  (entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      entry.target.dispatchEvent(
        new CustomEvent("intersect", { detail: entry.isIntersecting })
      );
    });
  }
);
```

And finally capture that event and modify the state:

```
<tr use:intersect
    on:intersect={(event) => (row.visible = event.detail)} >
  <td>{row.visible}</td>
</tr>
```

To render rows up to how many can fit on screen you could make the defaut state visible: true, and then wrap the element with an `{#if row.visible}<tr .... </tr>{/if}`. After the first event you would then remove the observer from the element using `observer.unobserve` by either updating the svelte action or in the observer hook.

Comment: thanks for your help @IamFro0sst! I am really looking for a way to limit the number of rendered rows, though. I think i found a way to do it in [the playground](https://svelte.dev/repl/4501039211944155bbd0078c07736c92?version=3.55.1) but perhaps there is a better way to do it. My Svelte-ish is very limited :(.